# Azure Data Factory retry and longRetry combined policy

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a policy where the pipeline will retry at 60 second intervals three times before doing a long retry twice at 1 hour intervals. Here is what I've tried:

Attempt 1:

```
"policy": {
        "validation": {
            "minimumSizeMB": 0.000005
        },
        "externalData": {
                "retry": 3,
        "retryInterval":60,
                "longRetry": 2,
                "longRetryInterval": "01:00:00"
        }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
"policy": {
    "retry": 3,
    "retryInterval":60,
    "longRetry": 2,
    "longRetryInterval": "01:00:00"
}
```

When I try to save these, the policy reverts back to its original settings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

LongRetry option is available only in ADF V1 and not in V2 as in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-pipelines).

A possible workaround is to duplicate the activity using “on failure”. First activity would use short retry, duplicated activity would use long retry. Duplicated activity would only be executed if the original ones fails.

In ADF V1 for below code:

"policy": {
"timeout": "1.00:00:00",
"concurrency": 1,
"executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
"style": "StartOfInterval",
"retry": 3,
"longRetry": 2,
"longRetryInterval": "00:30:00"
},

It means: upon failure, it will first retry 3 times in a row; if all 3 failed, then waiting for 30 minutes; after 30min, do another 3 retry attempts. The total retry Attempts is 3 x 2 = 6.